# Meteor - Tracker.autorun not refreshing data on update.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-dom

I have some basic code that I wrote for a texting app:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Tracker} from "meteor/tracker"

import {Texts} from "./../imports/api/Text";
import App from "./../imports/ui/App"

Meteor.startup(() => {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        let texts = Texts.find().fetch();
        console.log(texts)
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
    });
});
```

But the problem is when I go into the console, I get an empty array.

Text.js:

```
import {Mongo} from "meteor/mongo";

export const Texts = new Mongo.Collection("texts");
```

Am I missing something here in my main.js file or Text.js file? I'm not sure what to do now because I have copied and pasted this from my other project and it seems to not work here but it does in my old project.  I am out of solutions!! Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you still have the package `autopublish` installed, you need to publish the data from the server and subscribe to it on the client.

To publish, somewhere on the server you need:

```
import { Texts } from "/imports/api/Text";
Meteor.publish('texts', function () {
    return Texts.find();
});
```

And then before you use the collection, you need to subscribe on the client:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('texts'); // <--- 
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        let texts = Texts.find().fetch();
        console.log(texts)
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
    });
});
```

This article explains why:
https://medium.com/meteor-js/data-flow-from-the-database-to-the-ui-three-layers-of-meteor-d5e208b466c3

Comment: Thanks this works, but can you explain why my other code works and not this one, because I literally just copied and pasted it from and just changed a  few names(same pakages).  Could it be a new update in meteor because I updated meteor before made this new project?

Comment: check in your `.meteor/packages` file for `autopublish`. It could be that the other project has it installed and this one doesn't? Otherwise the data might already be subscribed from another place or in another template? When data is published to the client, it's available to any template, not just the one subscribing

Comment: I have autopublish version 1.0.7 installed and also I did not have to call meteor.subscribe/publish in my other project.  Do you know anything else that could possibly prevent the database from returning the data?

Comment: Somehow my code is now working without the code you gave me, and I did not do anything to it......Must be my a glitch or something.

Comment: Would seem a call to FETCH within tracker is required, to enable reactive collections.No idea why, since .ready() on the sub itself, should've done that as a ReactiveVar itself.

Comment: It's not really clear how that's relevant. Did you want to ask a new question?